# Trying to login to a website clicking a button

Tags: c#, wordpress, cookies, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control

I've just started playing around with C# few weeks ago. i got a task i am trying to perform and not sure if the way i do it now is the right approach.

I am trying to login to a website(in my case WordPress website- for lake of better options) and navigating in admin panel using C#

So far what I've done was creating a new project - Windows Form Application.

The following code - send a request to the website with password/username and other parameters as POST

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    CookieContainer cookieJar2 = new CookieContainer(); // will use this later
    string testaa = ""; // will use this later
    string paramaters = "log=xxxx&pwd=xxxx&testcookie=1&redirect_to=http://www.example.com/wp-admin/&wp-submit=Log In";
    string strResponse;
    HttpWebRequest requestLogin = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.lyndatobin-howes.com/wp-login.php");
    requestLogin.Method = "POST";
    requestLogin.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    requestLogin.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    requestLogin.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
    requestLogin.ContentLength = paramaters.Length;
    StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(requestLogin.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
    stOut.Write(paramaters);
    stOut.Close();
}
```

I then have this code to to take the cookie of the response.

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)requestLogin.GetResponse();
foreach (Cookie c in response.Cookies)
{
    cookieJar2.Add(new Cookie(c.Name, c.Value, c.Path, c.Domain));
}
```

then i have this to read the response + close some streams.

```
StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(requestLogin.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
strResponse = stIn.ReadToEnd();
string responseFromServer = stIn.ReadToEnd();
webBrowser1.DocumentText = responseFromServer;
stIn.Close();
response.Close();
```

And then i try using the above cookie for the page i am trying to access as follows :

```
HttpWebRequest requestLogin2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/wp-admin/");
requestLogin2.Method = "POST";
requestLogin2.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
requestLogin2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
requestLogin2.CookieContainer = cookieJar2;
requestLogin2.ContentLength = paramaters.Length;
StreamWriter stOut2 = new StreamWriter(requestLogin2.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
stOut2.Write(paramaters);
stOut2.Close();

StreamReader stIn2 = new StreamReader(requestLogin2.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
strResponse = stIn2.ReadToEnd();
string responseFromServer2 = stIn2.ReadToEnd();
webBrowser1.DocumentText = responseFromServer2;
richTextBox2.Text += "\n\n\n" + responseFromServer2;
stIn.Close();
```

Well it doesn't work for some reason I've been trying this for a week now.

I tried displaying the header - after the first request to see what headers i get back. and then looked at the cookie i built (cookieJar2) and it seem they aren't the same..

Anyways any help on the matter would be awesome and highly appreciated. i tried to give as much details as i could.

Comment: No matter what i do i keep only getting the response cookie and i think because of that i am missing the other 4 cookies.. don't know what to do with this.

Comment: Still Looking for any regarding the matter

Comment: No one ? not even direction ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice about your code is that you call `GetResponse()` twice in your initial login:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)requestLogin.GetResponse();
```

and

```
StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(requestLogin.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

As a result, you're making the login request *twice* and will be getting back two different cookies.  This will be why the cookie in `cookieJar2` doesn't match what you're outputting later.  Reuse your `response` object:

```
StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Next, when you try to load the admin page, don't `POST` to it.  Your second request should be a `GET` to retrieve the content of the page.